# Когда стоит передавать в сервисы бизнес-слоя текущего пользователя?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, архитектура

У Марка Симана в его книге Dependency Injection есть пример, когда он пишет сервис слоя бизнес-логики (страница 64):

> HomeController делегирует большую часть своей работы классу
>   ProductService, продемонстрированному в следующем листинге. Класс
>   ProductService соответствует классу Мэри с тем же именем, но на данный
>   момент он является подлинным классом доменной модели.

```
Листинг 2-6: Класс ProductService

public class ProductService
{
    private readonly ProductRepository repository;
    public ProductService(ProductRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        }
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public IEnumerable<DiscountedProduct> GetFeaturedProducts(IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        return from p in this.repository.GetFeaturedProducts() 
               select p.ApplyDiscountFor(user);
    }
}
```

Меня интересует вот этот момент, что в метод GetFeaturedProducts передаётся пользователь - а точнее оставшийся за кадром момент, делать ли так со всеми методами, чтобы бизнес-логика контролировала все операции и никак обойти её было нельзя.

Допустим, в приложении разрешено создавать продукты только сотрудникам, входящим в группу "администраторы". Реализовать это бизнес-требование в asp.net можно двумя способами:

- Просто навесить на метод контроллера атрибут `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` и на этом считать достаточным такую проверку. Где-то в бизнес-логике будет ProductService c методом Create. Во входных параметрах метода *не будет* передан пользователь.
- Проверить и на контроллере Authorize Roles и передавать внутрь *каждого метода* ProductService одним из параметров IPrincipal user.

Если читать рекомендации по архитектуре, то помимо ответственностей, которые относятся к одному конкретному слою - выделяются ещё и ответственности, которые "пронизывают все слои приложения" (логирование и та же авторизация).

Здесь такой же случай: непонятно, нужно ли подобные проверки делать только на уровне бизнес-логики или нужно дублировать и в слое приложения?

Comment: Мне кажется, в данном случае надо понять, является ли это требование требованием к бизнес-логике или требованием к приложению? Если оно выглядит как "юзеры, которые пытаются выполнить эту функцию из ВЕБ приложения должны быть админами" - это одно. Но если "только юзеры, которые являются администраторами выбранной группы товаров могут изменить товарные данные" - это другое.

Comment: @tym32167 Вопросы подобного плана у меня стали возникать, когда я стал представлять себе архитектуру не одиночного приложения, а в комплексе с другими. Представим, что рядом с веб-приложением планируется мобильное приложение. И мы хотим переиспользовать по-максимуму кода, поэтому активно выносим бизнес-логику в подходящий слой. Ответ для второго варианта очевиден, да?

Comment: Да я бы так не сказал. Если смотреть с такой стороны, то я бы API выделил бы в отдельный сервис, да и админку бы сделал отдедльным сервисом со своим API - тогда не важно, веб или мобилки, проверка юзера была бы на уровне API , но не в бизнес логике.

Comment: в своем приложении я использую [tag:autofac] при помощи которого я внедряю через конструктор `IPrincipal`, и получение текущего пользователя выглядит так: `principal.Identity.GetUserId<int>()` до этого мне приходилось в DTO модели добавлять свойство `public int Author {get; set;}` для передачи в бизнес слой. часть логики с использованием текущего пользователя, в частности доступ у меня остается в `gui` а прочая логика в бизнес слое